# Relationa database + ORM or Object oriented Database?

Tags: orm, object-oriented-database

Suppose I want to make one application in Object Oriented Programing language let i.e. Java

what is the better thing to do from following?

--Either Use Relational Database i.e. mySQL + Object Relation mapping i.e. Hibernate

or.

--Use Object Oriented Database i.e. db4o

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well that depends on the application, the data-set etc etc.

Both systems have their advantage. Take also a look at this [older stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800/object-oriented-vs-relational-databases).

Here's a few advantages of each system.

RDBMS + ORM:

- Lots of tools & libraries available for this combination.
- Lots of experience and knowledge available: Tutorials, Q&As, best pratices and people which can help are there.
- Fast for 'flat' data and 'reporting'-kinds of operations.
- Many languages, tools and libraries can talk to a RDBMS

ODBMS:

- Faster than a RDBMS + ORM for nested, complex datasets.
- No complex mapping required.

Drawbacks of each system:

RDBMS + ORM:

- Mapping between relational and objects is not trivial. Can lead to all kinds of performance issues.

ODBMS:

- Much, much smaller community and less tools.